# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS: No WiFi Adapter found

Tags: wireless, 18.04, network-manager, iwlwifi

All of a sudden I am getting errors with my WiFi adapter. I took my laptop to the office hooked up on the office WiFi worked all day like a charm, came home started having problems. At first I just killed and restarted Network Manager to resolve the problem, then is started getting worse and would not resolve. After reading several posts on the subject I uses the UKUU utility to update the kernel to 4.2+ as is recommended by Intel for my adapter (Wireless 7265) it worked for the evening and then in the morning after the machine woke up the problems started again.

This time the `lshw -c network` could not even see the adapter. Output of `lshw -c network`:

```
*-network DISABLED        
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7265
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: wlp7s0
   version: 3b
   serial: 60:57:18:18:10:46
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.20.5-042005-generic firmware=17.948900127.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:34 memory:d1500000-d1501fff


*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 01
       serial: 20:6a:8a:a2:0b:bc
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 duplex=full firmware=sb ip=192.168.0.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:37 memory:d1400000-d140ffff
```

```
justin@justin-Aspire-VN7-791:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    6.130977] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.948900127.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.162353] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x184
[    6.179938] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: base HW address: 60:57:18:18:10:46
[    6.247453] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    6.250027] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0 wlp7s0: renamed from wlan0
[   16.462415] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[   16.462494] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Error sending MCAST_FILTER_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[   16.462498] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: mcast filter cmd error. ret=-5
[   26.094305] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[   26.094312] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
[   26.094372] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 00000000: 095a8086 00100000 0280003b 00000000 00000004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   26.094377] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 50108086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 00000100
[   26.094380] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[   26.094418] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[   26.094422] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[   26.094428] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: iwlwifi device AER capability structure:
[   26.094460] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 00000000: 14010001 00100000 00000000 00462031 00002000 00002000 00000014 40000001
[   26.094463] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 00000020: 0000000f d1500460 00000000
[   26.094466] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.0) config registers:
[   26.094496] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.0: 00000000: 8c148086 00100407 060400d5 00810010 00000000 00000000 00070700 200000f0
[   26.094500] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.0: 00000020: d150d150 0001fff1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 00000000 0000030b
[   26.094543] WARNING: CPU: 7 PID: 0 at /build/linux-dCj7xI/linux-4.15.0/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:1973 iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0xea/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[   26.094544] Modules linked in: ccm binfmt_misc arc4 intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp joydev kvm_intel snd_hda_codec_hdmi kvm snd_hda_codec_realtek irqbypass iwlmvm snd_hda_codec_generic crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel mac80211 pcbc snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core uvcvideo snd_hwdep aesni_intel snd_pcm videobuf2_vmalloc aes_x86_64 iwlwifi crypto_simd glue_helper snd_seq_midi videobuf2_memops cryptd snd_seq_midi_event videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_rawmidi intel_cstate input_leds intel_rapl_perf videodev rtsx_usb_ms memstick hid_multitouch serio_raw media cfg80211 snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd soundcore mei_me ie31200_edac mei shpchp acer_wmi lpc_ich sparse_keymap mac_hid wmi_bmof sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables
[   26.094632] RIP: 0010:iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0xea/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[   26.094657]  iwl_read_prph+0x38/0x90 [iwlwifi]
[   26.094666]  iwl_trans_pcie_log_scd_error+0x125/0x1f0 [iwlwifi]
[   26.094673]  ? iwl_pcie_txq_build_tfd+0xe0/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[   26.094680]  iwl_pcie_txq_stuck_timer+0x46/0x70 [iwlwifi]
[   26.149584] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Queue 10 is active on fifo 2 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [60, 170] HW [90, 90] FH TRB=0x05a5a5a5a
[   31.985837] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[   31.985860] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[   31.985862] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
[  950.788367] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  950.788418] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Error sending MAC_CONTEXT_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  950.788422] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Failed to send MAC context (action:2): -5
[  950.788426] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: failed to update MAC 60:57:18:18:10:46
[  950.806889] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  950.806915] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Error sending MAC_PM_POWER_TABLE: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  950.806929] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: failed to update power mode
[  960.917743] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Queue 5 is active on fifo 2 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [5, 6] HW [90, 90] FH TRB=0x05a5a5a5a
[  971.633538] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  971.633642] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  971.633650] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
```

Comment: It looks like the 4.20 kernel is too new. Boot with the original kernel. 4.15 > 4.2

Comment: yes I tried that, the reason I upgraded the kernel was because of the information given by Intel for my adapter.
[link]
(https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) _italic_ **bold**  'code'
You can see here that the Wireless 7265 requires the 4.2+ kernel. Stumped!

Comment: The 4.15 is 4.2+. You can always boot with a previous kernel and then remove the 4.20.

Comment: How confusing... I will roll it back and update on the results.

Comment: No go, once booted I tested wifi by opening youtube, it opened and then hung. So the wifi adapter was working for a few seconds and then bailed.

Comment: Opening youtube is not the best way to test ;-) Please [edit] your question and add output of `dmesg | grep iwl`. And since it connected and started working all is OK with the drivers.

Comment: This a real issue. `iwlwifi` crashes. I can suggest to report it to Launchpad as a bug or write to kernel maintainers.

Comment: Yes it is a real problem, sorry I posted the results of dmesg | grep iwl - interested to know what might be the solution.

Comment: It is very hard to tell what is the issue. Generally these adapters work well. I am afraid it is a hardware issue, or some very specific kernel bug.

Comment: Last night I put the live cd in and it was working fine, today I tried the live cd again and I had the same problems with the live cd (not working) so maybe it is a hardware problem? any ideas how I could confirm the is not software?

Comment: Most likely it is a hardware issue then.

Comment: maybe when you notice that it is not working you can put the output of sudo networkctl list in your question. That may show if your adapter is up and working
and networkctl status can help as well

Comment: I just found something pretty valuable, I tried to turn on bluetooth and the machine is saying there is no bluetooth. So it looks like the card is fried. At least that puts an end to the agony of trying to work out wtf is going.

Comment: ```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

```

Comment: @Pilot6 spaseba!

Comment: Try in terminal `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` reboot